# gif animation set up once running only once

Tags: css, image, animated-gif

I have one png image and another gif image. And the gif image is made from photoshop with setting for once.

[image]

Now when I hover the button then `background-image` is changed with the gif image but if again hovered then it will change the background image to gif file but not animating.

Is there any solution for this?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2bCMp/)

Comment: This might differ between browsers (in Opera I see the animation every time I hover over the element). But instead of using a GIF for this, I’d suggest to use CSS animations and transforms in the first place …

Comment: also on windows firefox 28 I cant see any animation at all

Answer (score 2):

Displaying a .gif on hover isn't really the best way to go about this, due to compatibility with other browsers. Maybe you could consider using CSS animations? Here's a cool library made up of some CSS keyframe animations.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

The flipOutX animation might be a close match to what you want.

Comment: No, there are more effects...You'll see in the dropdown from that page

Comment: @BeatAlex https://github.com/daneden/animate.css You can download stylesheets for the individual animations here instead of having one large stylesheet for all the animations.

Comment: You can choose from there depends on what animation you want. No need whole css.

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bCMp/5/)

Think this is what you wanted:

HTML:

```
<div id="btn">demo</div>
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:200px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:55px;
  top: 19px;
  right: 107px;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

#btn:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: tilt;
  animation-name: tilt;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
}

@-webkit-keyframes tilt {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
  }
}

@keyframes tilt {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(45deg);
  }
}
```